# Smoothing buildings created from LiDAR to Raster/TIN using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: dem, lidar, 3d-analyst, arcgis-pro, las

I have just started working with LiDAR data. My end result would be a DSM.

To start with creating this I used the tools `LAS to Raster` and `LAS to TIN`. With both the results I'm getting an outcome looking like this:

[image: Outcome conversion]

I've made sure it takes the maximum value while converting. Anyone knows how to improve the quality of the created buildings? I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: related (not arcgis): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78240/how-to-de-noise-a-dsm/86662#86662